# tensorflow does not learn, I get a straight line only

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, lstm

I have the following model :

```
var model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape : [1], units : 9, activation: 'sigmoid'}));
        model.add(tf.layers.reshape({targetShape: [3,3]}));
        model.add(tf.layers.lstm({
            units: 9,
            recurrentInitializer: 'glorotNormal',
            activation: 'sigmoid'
        }));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units : 1, activation: 'sigmoid'}));
        model.compile({
            loss: 'meanSquaredError',
            optimizer: 'adam',
            metrics: ['accuracy']
        });
```

I train it like the following :

```
var t0 = performance.now();
                const history = await model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, {
                    epochs: 1,
                    batchSize : 128
                });

                yPredict = model.predict(xPredict).as1D();
                var t1 = performance.now();
```

A call to my own render() function shows, that even after 10 epochs 
I have only a straight line, not interpolating the sine function in xTrain/yTrain.
xTrain/yTrain is a sine function with 1000 samples

Comment: looks pointless what kind of dataset you have? i am not judging you just if we know what problem this model tring to fix we can help you more officent

Comment: I am not too familiar with java script version of tensorflow but this looks like you are inputting 1 value per each input, using dense layer to output 9 values, reshaping it to [3,3] and then feeding that into LSTM. Outputs of dense layers are not sequential, and thus is not a sequential data that LSTM can explore.

Comment: Yes that with the sequential is my problem. I want to guess stock prices of the future. The input to the nn is time € [0..1], and the ouput shall be the price € [0..1]

Comment: So you'd have to have input in the shape of [x1,x2,..], and an output of [x2,x3,...] In which case the input shape probably will be [sequence length, 1]. which outputs units of 1 for each sequence so [sequence length,1]

Comment: I input shape [1] to the nn and get an output shape of [1] from the nn

Comment: You mentioned you are getting a straight line. What is the output value in that case? Is it 0, or a random value? Also make sure that you've normalized your input data to be in the range [0,1] - same with your output. Also if you can share a plot/chat of your data and the model prediction, it will helps us debug it. Another idea: try simplifying the model (make it couple dense layers with sigmoids) and see if you still get a straight line.